# Java Android. Запись экрана (скриншот) и ее передача

Tags: java, android, клиент-сервер, udp

Я **начинающий** в программировании, и мне с одноклассником (оба из 11 класса) нужно сделать проект, который будет чем-то напоминать демонстрацию экрана в скайпе, только на андроиде.

На данный момент я сделал сервер через протокол udp (через datagramsocket and datagrampacket). При первом приеме данных я "инициализирую нового пользователя", то есть присваиваю добавляю нового "клиента" в хеш таблицу с ключом, основаном на IP-адресе и порту клиента. Далее я принимаю от клиентов массив байтов, первый байт которого обозначает id "клиента" (мне пока что хватает 256 клиентов). Далее данные, которые нужно передать. Я, удаляя первый элемент массива, передаю его нужному "клиенту". Если интересно, вот [код](https://github.com/savelyevlad/UDPServer/tree/anotherFreakingAttempToDoItWell).

Я хочу узнать, как можно делать запись экрана андроид-устройства в реальном времени, используя Java, и передавать его через datagramsocket. Была идея делать много скриншотов и отправлять их, и я даже нашел, [как это сделать](https://github.com/mtsahakis/MediaProjectionDemo/blob/master/src/com/mtsahakis/mediaprojectiondemo/ScreenCaptureImageActivity.java), но в этом коде я понимаю только то, что он делает много скриншотов, и знаю, где он записывает эти скриншоты в Bitmap и вместе с этим сохраняет в файлы. Возможно, этот вариант неверный, или есть лучше? К тому же я столкнулся с тем, что я не смог быстро добавлять скриншоты в ImageView, приложение попросту вылетало (по этой же причине я не знаю, как часто делаются скриншоты в единицу времени). Еще мне кажется, что передача каждой картинки может оказаться медленной, также ее сжатие может замедлить программу.

В итоге, вот мои вопросы:

Как делать запись экрана андроид устройства и передавать их через datagramsocket? Оптимально ли делать отдельно каждый скриншот отдельно и передавать их? Если да, то как организовать видеотрансляцию? Как тогда правильно выбирать сжатие картинки, чтоб была наибольшая скорость? Также как передавать картинки, размер которых получился больше 64 кБ? Придется их разделять на несколько отправок, но тогда как понять, что 2 отправки являются одной картинкой, и понять в какой последовательности они были приняты?

P.S. Если нужно больше информации от меня, спрашивайте. Проект сдавать меньше, чем через месяц, поэтому нужно как можно быстрее все сделать, чтоб подготовить доклад и документацию.

Comment: Приведите точный текст задания. Существует вероятность, что вы изначально пошли не тем путем.

Comment: Это выпускная работа в лицее, то есть аналог дипломной в университете. Тема работы: "Демонстрация экрана Android-устройства на экран другого Android-устройства".

Comment: Ну тогда вы поздновато спохватились :) Конкретное ТЗ на "демонстрацию экрана" какое? Нужно прям гнать видео поток, или достаточно "нажал кнопку и скриншот улетел на другой телефон"?

Comment: Ну тогда вы поздновато спохватились :) Конкретное ТЗ на "демонстрацию экрана" какое? Нужно прям гнать видео поток, или достаточно "нажал кнопку и скриншот улетел на другой телефон"?

Comment: Нужно гнать видеопоток. Один клиент демонстрирует (делится (share)) свой экран, и может, допустим, в это время играть. Другой же будет смотреть эту демонстрацию, и видеть что происходит на экране другого смартфона. Так поздно получилось из-за большой загруженности в учебе и потому что мы изначально не разбирались в теме "клиент-серверные приложение", и нужно было все учить. Кстати, передать картинку мы смогли (но размерами меньше 64 кБ).

Comment: Хмм, я бы использовал Api типо RemoteDisplayApi или TeamViewer. Я делал такое кстати через WebView, и использовал какой-то сервис, но лучше Api, нативный, там и поддержка хоть будет и хоть как-то владеть ситуацией будете. Самому написать тоже можно, но если нормально делать не думаю, что новичками за 1 месяц можно что-то сделать. Вы это время потратите  только на поверхностное изучение NDK, openGl, ну и мб как хендлить треды, ну и ловить утечки, но не более. Иначе все что делаете, можно в мусор выкидывать, никому это не пригодится